# on image load dosomething(this) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have an image $("#main")

how can I use jquery to dosomething(this) when the image has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`load()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/load) event.

```
$("#main").load(doSomething);
```

Within your `doSomething()` method, `this` will refer to the DOM image element. Note that it isn't passed as an argument. Just use `this` within your `doSomething()` method and it will work.

Keep in mind that the `load()` event will only fire if the element isn't already loaded. If the image is already loaded, then `doSomething` will never get called.